# References for Probability Theory using Differential Forms?

Tags: probability-theory, differential-geometry, reference-request, soft-question

Is there some known work or theory of probability that uses differential forms? I know the basics of probability, but I know there're notions of pushforward and pullback measures which they do sound like the notions in differential geometry.

Can you give some references?

Comment: Any measure theoretic probability book . Schilling Durrett Bogachev

Comment: But they are not what you think they are. For differential geometric ideas in probability you might want stochastic geometry or processes on manifolds

Comment: @badatmath Can you give me full titles please?